# HTML to PDF conversion in ios

Tags: iphone, html, ios, pdf

I have a huge html file with data programmatically changing.  I want to convert this html into PDF and email it as an attachment.  Can someone please suggest can I achieve this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create all "image" PDF, which means all text will be image (no vector) it's very easy. Essentially it is like below

Open HTML in UIWebView

Capture the web view, part by part by rendering it into an image context. In other words, we will take a snapshot of the web view, render it into an image context, and save it to our documents directory. We will then programmatically scroll the web view, again take a screenshot and save it, and repeat the process till we reach the end of the web view.

See the details [here](http://www.ioslearner.com/convert-html-uiwebview-pdf-iphone-ipad/)